# Selecting rows as columns with case on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case, inner-join

What i want to achieve is To add names to my current select and for all the highlighted cells to be on the same row
[image: SQL RESULTS]

right now I am getting to this result with

```
   Select

        CASE sc.Tipo WHEN 1 THEN
                sc.SaldoIni  ELSE 0 END,
        CASE sc.Tipo WHEN 2 THEN
                sc.Importes1 ELSE 0 END,
        CASE sc.Tipo WHEN 3 THEN
                sc.Importes1 ELSE 0 END,
        CASE sc.Tipo WHEN 1 THEN 
                sc.Importes1 ELSE 0 END

        FROM        SaldosCuentas sc

        INNER JOIN  Cuentas c
        ON          
        c.Id = sc.IdCuenta WHERE sc.Ejercicio = 13 and sc.IdCuenta = 131
```

how would i go about putting all the highlighted text on one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put those case statements inside a SUM function for your query to return 1 row.

`SUM(CASE sc.Tipo WHEN 1 THEN sc.SaldoIni  ELSE 0 END) AS SaldoIni`